# Rendering complexity of a complex object

Tags: 3d, rendering, time-complexity, rasterizing, zbuffer

Consider a 3D box. Re-tessellating the vertices of this box in a random fashion creates many large intersecting faces. Rendering such an object is more complex. why? How does this affect the rendering complexity?

Answer (score 0):

Tesselation of 3D object faces in "random" fashion is not very clearly defined, and it also depends on what type of complexity you are talking.

If you are doing the tesselation on the CPU side, you have to send over much more vertex and face information to the hardware to render the same object, and the rendering cost also increases. If polygons or quads that overlap, the problem is even worse because fragments are possibly shaded multiple times.

If tesselation is occuring on the GPU side, the complexity is also higher due to the evaluation of each and every framgent input in the tess-eval and geometry shader stages. Here, the tesselation is hardly random since there are only 2 types of tesselation: triangle-based and patch-based.

Comment: You answer is not relevant to my question. I haven't asked about the complexity of the tessellation process. Consider two objects, each with n points and n triangles. One of the objects has a smooth surface, and the other one has many large intersecting faces. The connectivity information (such as *.OBJ) is given to the graphics pipeline. My question is what is the impact of having larger intersecting faces on the rendering time? I have animated the rotation of a smooth surface with n triangles and a fuzzy onion-layered object with n triangles, and I have calculated the time.

Comment: Surprisingly, the fuzzy onion-layered object was rendered much quicker! This contradicts your hypothesis.

Comment: My apologies, dealing with GPU tessellation daily got me triggered by that part. Still, it's odd that your complexity *drops* when rendering overlapping triangles. Things that also play a part are the number of fragments shaded in both tests, and differences in shader complexity (lighting, maps) and all sorts of other bindings, uploads etc. Probably also starts affecting performance once you pass a certain point where scene-complexity fills all parallel threads on your GPU.